# Most efficient way to iterate over large vector?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an input ndarray, `pointsCount`, with shape (4000000, 1). I have another ndarray, `clusters`, with shape (2,1). I then want to perform the following:

```
distances = np.zeros((pointsCount, n_clusters))
for x in range(len(trainPoints)):
    for c in range(len(clusters)):
        distances[x,c] = (trainPoints[x]-clusters[c]).T@(trainPoints[x]-clusters[c])
```

However, this takes *ages* to complete. The same is true for the list comprehension `distances = np.array([(x-cluster).T@(x-cluster) for x in trainPoints for cluster in clusters]).reshape((4000000, 2))`.

Any way that I can perform this faster using numpy?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html?

Comment: Nono, it does not have to be this exact case. I am asking about the general case where you will perform math expressions for each iteration :)

Comment: The general answer is "vectorize it", which depends on your operations

Comment: Did you check the results, is this what you expected? I mean you are essentially squaring the result of `(pointsCount - clusters)` and thus you don't need the `.T` (transpose) or `@` for that matter. If that is the case, then I can write a faster answer.

Comment: @SayandipDutta The results are as expected and I am aware of the fact that I can remove the `.T` but I have chosen not to because it better resembles matrix algebra :))

Comment: Since you are calling the math expression once for each element of the array, there isn't much you can do to improve the iteration.  Most of time cost is in those calls, not the iteration (or accumulation) mechanism.  For a major speed improvement you have to move the math operations into whole-array compiled `numpy` methods/operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is transpose `clusters`. For example, given initial arrays:

```
>>> pointsCount    # I have considered 4 instead of 4 mil
array([[2],
       [4],
       [7],
       [6]])
>>> clusters
array([[2],
       [3]])
# Your code:
>>> np.array([(x-cluster).T@(x-cluster) for x in pointsCount for cluster in clusters]).reshape((4, 2))
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 4,  1],
       [25, 16],
       [16,  9]])

# Faster code:
>>> (pointsCount - clusters.T)**2 
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 4,  1],
       [25, 16],
       [16,  9]], dtype=int32)
```

You may want to take a look at [`NumPy Broadcasting`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html#broadcasting)

Comment: Wutttt, gosh it is faster! By a very large magnitude!